# return statement in binary search

Tags: c, recursion, return-value

I have a little confusion in the following two statements.

The below program is `finds the index of an element out of a sorted array[no duplicates] using binary search.`

```
int bin(int *arr,int l,int h,int k)
{
    int mid;
    if(l>h)
            return -1;
    if(l==h)
    {
            return arr[l]==k?l:-1;
    }
    else
    {
            mid=(l+h)>>1;
            if(arr[mid]==k)
                    return mid;
            else if(k>arr[mid])
                    bin(arr,mid+1,h,k);
            else
                    bin(arr,l,mid-1,k);
    }
}
```

I do not have any problem in the program[working perfectly]:

I have confusion in following two statements:

bin(arr,l,mid-1,k);         http://ideone.com/p1o5U
return bin(arr,l,mid-1,k);  http://ideone.com/lMhgB

Using any of the above statement gives correct result.
**Which statement is more efficient in terms of time?**
`How the program is working fine even without return statement?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How the program is working fine even without return statement?

In this case I'd say there is no difference in practice, as the recursion ends to a return statement irrelevant of which parameters you give to it (yes, even though you don't specify it in the last two calls). This is however a compiler-specific detail that you should not rely on!

> Which statement is more efficient in terms of time?

You might consider the ones with the return statement a bit more efficient as in that case it doesn't need to read up on the "else" check, however, the difference is very small.

---

Do note however that without return statements it is considered "incorrect", even though it "works", and -Wall should give you warnings about it.

See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772906/recursive-functions-in-c-is-return-always-necessary) also. Copied from that answer:

> What you see is probably caused by the implementation detail that
>   function on some architectures return (integral values) by setting a
>   well known register to that value (eax on i386). Therefore, if the
>   bottommost recursive call does return and set this register, and the
>   calls in-between don't stomp on that register, you see that it sort of
>   works. However, you mustn't rely on that.

Edit: changed the wording as to not imply the behaviour as a deliberate optimization. Don't know if it is or not. It is anyway something that some compilers do and some don't.

Comment: "the compiler figures out what you're trying to do" - no it doesn't... "a compiler optimization" - nope...

Comment: ok. could you care to explain then why results are different on different compilers as pointed out in the other answer?

Comment: you already have the answer in your last (copied) paragraph. it's not an optimiziation or clever compiler, it's just that the emitted code is different. your first paragraph is completely wrong.

Comment: To me it would sound to a compiler optimization to use the same register in this kind of a case. But ok, the behaviour is dependent on the compiler being used, be it optimization or not.

Answer (score 0):

This program produces different results when compiled with different compilers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bin(int *arr,int l,int h,int k)
{
    int mid;
    if(l>h)
            return -1;
    if(l==h)
    {
            return arr[l]==k?l:-1;
    }
    else
    {
            mid=(l+h)>>1;
            if(arr[mid]==k)
                    return mid;
            else if(k>arr[mid])
                    bin(arr,mid+1,h,k);
            else
                    bin(arr,l,mid-1,k);
    }
}

int arr[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
    printf("bin(%d): %d\n", i, bin(arr, 0, 9, i));
  return 0;
}
```

Output (compiler: Open Watcom C/C++ 1.9):

```
>nrv.exe
bin(0): 0
bin(1): 1
bin(2): 2
bin(3): 3
bin(4): 4
bin(5): 4
bin(6): 6
bin(7): 7
bin(8): 8
bin(9): 9
bin(10): 10
bin(11): 11
```

Output (compiler: MinGW gcc 4.6.2):

```
$ nrv.exe
bin(0): -1
bin(1): 0
bin(2): 1
bin(3): 2
bin(4): 3
bin(5): 4
bin(6): 5
bin(7): 6
bin(8): 7
bin(9): 8
bin(10): 9
bin(11): -1
```

I wouldn't dare to say *I do not have any problem in the program[working perfectly]*. Your `bin()` function invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: i am using ideone(gcc-4.3.4) & its working perfectly there as you might see i have also given the links.

Comment: Your code is extremely brittle. A different compiler, a different optimization option, different code around `bin()` can and often will break it.

Answer (score 0):

Off topic: if you are going to use recursion anyway, you can simplify the program a lot by eliminating the lower boundary, and bump the pointer instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bin(int *arr, int n, int k);
int bin(int *arr, int n, int k)
{
    int mid;
    if (n <= 0) return -1;

    mid = n / 2;
    if (arr[mid] == k) return mid;
    if (k < arr[mid]) return bin(arr, mid, k);

    n = bin(arr+mid+1, n-(mid+1), k);
    return (n<0) ? n : mid+1+n;
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
    int result, val;

    for (val= -2; val < 15; val++) {
        result = bin(array, 10, val);
        printf("Val=%d -> %d\n", val, result);
        }
return 0;
}
```